# My array despite following normal initialization refuses to be the right size

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, vector

I am in a data structures course right now and I am designing my own array class for use in a project. While testing my methods, the program kept giving me garbage when I attempt to return values. After using visual studio's debugger, I managed to narrow the problem down to the resize function and more specificly the resizeArray. No matter what I enter for its size, it only has one entry and I can't figure out why. I've attempted using flat values as well as the dynamic ones I would be using in the final version.

This is the class I've been writing.

```
#include "ArrayClass.h";
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template  <class T>
ArrayClass<T>::ArrayClass() {
    thisArray = new T[1];
    length = 1;
}

template  <class T>
ArrayClass<T>::ArrayClass(T element) {
    thisArray = new T[1];
    thisArray[0] = element;
    length = 1;
    currentLastElement = 0;
}

template  <class T>
ArrayClass<T>::ArrayClass(T element, int x) {
    thisArray = new T[x];
    thisArray[0] = element;
    length = x;
    currentLastElement = 0;
}

template  <class T>
void ArrayClass<T>::addElement(T element) {
    if (currentLastElement >= (length - 1)) {
        resize(length);
        length++;
        thisArray[currentLastElement + 1] = element;
        cout << thisArray[currentLastElement + 1];
        currentLastElement += 1;
    }
    else {
        thisArray[currentLastElement + 1] = element;
        currentLastElement += 1;
    }
}

template  <class T>
void ArrayClass<T>::addElement(T element, int x) {
    T tempElement;
    if (x == currentLastElement + 1) {
        this.addElement(element);
    }
    else {
        tempElement = *thisArray[x];
        thisArray[x] = element;
        addElement(tempElement, x + 1);
    }
}

template  <class T>
void ArrayClass<T>::removeElement(int x) {
    delete[x] thisArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLastElement; i++) {
        cout << thisArray[1];
        thisArray[x] = thisArray[x + 1];
        x++;
    }   
}

template  <class T>
T ArrayClass<T>::accessElement(int x) {
    return thisArray[x];
}

template <class T>
void ArrayClass<T>::resize(int x) {
    T * resizeArray;
    resizeArray = new T[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) resizeArray[i] = thisArray[i];
    thisArray = resizeArray;
};
```

This is what I've been using to test it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayClass.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ArrayClass<int> intArray(1);
    intArray.addElement(5);
    cout << intArray.accessElement(0);
    cout << intArray.accessElement(1);
    intArray.removeElement(0);
    cout << intArray.accessElement(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: is this correct: `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) resizeArray[i] = thisArray[i];`? no matter how big your new array, you fill it using "old" `length`, therefore the rest of it is garbage. just a guess, though. in other words, you do not update `length` member variable, thus it gives you wrong number of elements when you use it.

Comment: I just want an array that's big enough that I can continue to fill it. I deliberately leave the space empty. The point of the function is to be able to expand on the original array. So, it copies the contents of the the first into a larger undefined second array. Also, even if my program doesn't know how long the array is, visual studio should.

Comment: `delete[x] thisArray;` does not remove an element from the array. In fact, it shouldn't compile at all. (There is no way to remove individual element from an array.)

Answer (score 1):

In `ArrayClass<T>::addElement(T element)`, you're calling `resize` as

```
resize(length);
```

which doesn't extends the array. You need

```
resize(length + 1);
```

BTW1: You need to `delete[]` the original array in `resize`, otherwise it'll be memory leak. Such as,

```
template <class T>
void ArrayClass<T>::resize(int x) {
    ...
    delete[] thisArray;
    thisArray = resizeArray;
};
```

BTW2: `this.addElement(element);` and `delete[x] thisArray;` won't compile.

Comment: It doesn't help, I even tried changing the size of resizeArray to a flat 5 and visual studio still treated it like it was only one value.

Comment: @user2226282 You might want VS knows `thisArray` is an array with 5 elements after `thisArray = new T[x];`. I'm not farmiliar with VS, I guess `thisArray` is just a `int*` to VS, it won't know whether it's an array (and the size) or not.

Comment: I posted another screenshot of what I get when I run the code.

Comment: It's really weird, I've walked through the code and it should work perfectly except the second time around, it just fails.

Comment: There are a couple of test output lines to make sure.